# PHP mod rewrite redirection going the wrong way

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to get a php site I am making to have similar seo friendly urls like the wordpress sites do sometimes. For instance, I want mysite.com/page.php?section=great to appear as mysite.com/great.

I have been working through other tutorials and this site trying to get this working and it seems I am only able to get it working backwards. That is, I type mysite.com/great and the user will see mysite.com/page.php?section=great, but it won't work the other way around.

Here is my code in my .htaccess file...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /([^/]*)$ http://www.mysite.com.au/really/long/url/page.php?section=$1 [R]
```

I have tried reversing the above code so the /$ section is on the right of the actual full url, but not sure if that is actually correct or not. Never worked with mod rewrite before and finding this very frustrating. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it true that any resource that doesn't exist should be redirected to *page.php*?

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /really/long/url/page.php\?section=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

It has to match against the actual request and not the URI because the URI is being mangled by the other rules that you have.